# How JVM distinguish between Scala bytecode and Java bytecode?

Tags: java, scala, jvm, bytecode

As Scala also produces bytecode and executed by JVM. I am wondering How JVM distinguish between Scala bytecode and Java bytecode. Can anyone please explain?

```
 Scalac Myprogram.scala
 java Myprogram
```

So this statements are perfectly fine?

Comment: The JVM only sees byte code.  It doesn't behave differently.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> I am wondering How JVM distinguish between Scala bytecode and Java bytecode.

It doesn't. There is no such thing as Scala bytecode. The Scala compiler compiles to JVM bytecode. Just like the Java compiler also compiles to JVM bytecode.

The JVM doesn't know anything about Scala. It doesn't know anything about Java, either. Nor does it know anything about Groovy, Clojure, Kotlin, Ceylon, Fantom, Ruby, Python, ECMAScript, or any of the other ~400 programming languages for which there are implementations on the JVM.

The JVM only knows about one language: JVM bytecode.

Note that this is really no different from any other machine, virtual or not. The CLR only knows about CIL, it knows nothing about C#, VB.NET, or F#. An Intel Core CPU knows only about AMD64 and x86 machine code, it knows nothing about C, C++, Objective-C, Swift, Go, Java, Python. The CPython VM only knows about CPython bytecode, it knows nothing about Python.

Comment: Then, can we use the same JVM for both scala and java...?

Comment: You cannot use a JVM for either Scala or Java. You can only use a JVM for JVM bytecode. The JVM doesn't know anything about Scala. The JVM doesn't know anything about Java. The only thing it understands is JVM bytecode.

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't. Scala compiles to the same bytecode as Java.

Answer (score 5):

A picture is worth a thousand words

[image: Scala Runtime]

Answer (score 4):

Both `scalac` and `javac` generate bytecode. The JVM doesn't care how the bytecode was produced, it's all the same to the JVM.

However, `scala` and `java` sets up the boot CLASSPATH differently, so if your code contains Scala Runtime Library calls, and it very likely will, it needs to be run by `scala`, not `java`.

You *can* setup the boot CLASSPATH manually using `java`, if you absolutely have to, but why go through all that extra work, when `scala` will do it for you?

Answer (score 1):

Scala compiles to normal Java bytecode, so the JVM doesn't seem any difference. The extra features of Scala that Java doens't have are implemented through a combination of compile time passes and runtime helper functions. If you disassemble generated Scala classes, you'll probably see tons of calls to the Scala runtime for stuff like boxing and unboxing arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The byte code as defined in the standard is the same in the point of view of the executor. But when you work with a debugger, more information is needed to match the correct language and source files.

The only way to indicate what is the source code from which the JVM bytecode has been generated is through optional class attributes `SourceFile` (from Java 1.0.2) and `SourceDebugExtension` (from Java 5.0).
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.10 and 11

An additional information will give the line numbers of the various objects in the source `LineNumberTable`, this also is optional.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.12

You can find the equivalent for other JVM specs.

These are used by IDEs to get the context of JVM class, but are optional values and debug information depends on the compiler.

So it can be an info to know what the compiler was, but you cannot rely on it as sure info. If it's defined, it should be in the compiler definition.

With scalac you can switch the information storage with the -g option, the same as javac except the `notc` as Java doesn't manage TCO:

`g:{none,source,line,vars,notc}
   "none" generates no debugging info,
   "source" generates only the source file attribute,
   "line" generates source and line number information,
   "vars" generates source, line number and local variable information,
   "notc" generates all of the above and will not perform tail call optimization.`

By default `line`

To get a ClassLoader to retrieve info from the class files you can use the Open Source library ASM : http://asm.ow2.org/

You can also parse the class file or internal storage by yourself, it is not very difficult retrieving class attributes.